# If New Document/Media uploaded in liferay by admin, user has to get message after login

Tags: liferay

I am very new to liferay. Please help me implementing the below requirement.

- Using Document and media portlet in `liferay`, If any new document is uploaded or uploaded document is modified(Version changed) by admin user, then
- How can i identify that the particular document is modified or newly uploaded as i have to show a popup message to user based upon if any new files is uploaded or modified after log on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not a little change request - this required bit more development. And here is more different variants:

Simple but nonperformance variant:

- With UserLocalServiceUtil you can check the last user-login date
- Similarly iterate over all documents and check last modification date
- Create Liferay-Portlet that shows the list of documents with modification date after last user-login date

~

Comment: Thanks for suggestion Mark! It is really a good idea to proceed with.

Answer (score 1):

Here are the steps:

- Use corresponding **Document Listener i.e
  DlFolderListener or DlFileEntryListener.** You have to use hook to
  add your listner in portal.properties.
- For Example, you would need to workaround below property.

> ```
> value.object.listener.com.liferay.portlet.documentlibrary.model.FileEntry
>    = com.my.custom.MyFileEntryListener
> ```

- This class would be extending `BaseModelListener<FileEntry>`
- Override and use onAfterUpdate method to notify appropriate audience
  (users).
- Now this can be done by setting this notification in user
  preferences.
- On user Login, check corresponding user preferences for this
  notification and notify user. You can use hook `LoginPostAction` to read user preferences for notification.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create customfield for user. Create table with service builder to store the fileEntry Id which modified.
2. Create DLFileEntry Listener and write
   code on FileUpdate. Add DLFileEntryID in same table created in step 1. Set
   custom field true for all the user.
3. Create LoginPostActionHook and on Check the user's flag and fetch the FileEntryId get info of that fileEntryId and display notification with all file's information. Set customfield Flag false for particular user and remove the fileentryid from table or mark them all as read.